# Apt only displays orange letters; Apt-get white ones

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, colors, aptitude

For some time now I have been wondering why, sometimes, I saw an orange output for when updating or installing some stuff. I discovered now that when I use `apt` (like: sudo apt upgrade) the download will be shown in orange color:

[image]

But, when I type in `apt-get` (like: sudo apt-get upgrade) the color comes out as white.

I use Linux Mint sharply updated now. But have seen the same in the past on other Ubuntu flavors.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: `apt` was introduced for easier/higher level usage (i.e. by normal humans) in place of the older `apt-get`. Regarding specific colors, my guess would be the default yellow/orange of `apt` simply distinguishings it from `apt-get` on the command line (note that there are differences in commands between the two).

Comment: I see @Anaksunaman! Appreciated your comment, very! I'll do some research on the differences between them both and, also, that's what I was thinking right before reading your opinion: It might be just to differentiate!